# xml parsing error error Unmarshaling failed due to :Parsing Error : Character reference "&#56227;" is an invalid XML character

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

> Blockquote

Parser is failing at ¾Ë°Ú¾î¿° ¾ó¸¶³ª °Å¸±°Í°°¾Æ¿° with message Unmarshaling failed due to :
Parsing Error :

```
Character reference "&#56227;" is an invalid XML character.

converted internally to &#65533;&#752;&#1726;&#61424; &#65533;&#56227;&#56755;&#65533; &#65533;&#376;&#65533;&#65533;&#880;&#65533;&#65533;&#447;&#65533; &#65533;&#65533; &#65533;&#65533;&#65533;&#65533; &#65533;&#1008;&#65533; &#65533;&#1460;&#176;&#65533;? by parser while parsing
```

effitively failing at ³ character.

Now my question is what option i have to make it go through? I tried putting data in cdata section but it still fails.
I am using old **castor.jar and xerces.jar with jdk 1.4**  which i can not change.
to add more details - big file have xml data in like  ¾Ë°Ú¾î¿° ¾ó¸¶³ª °Å¸±°Í°°¾Æ¿°data> now this file is processed using sax parser. 
on strartElement we again start collecting data and on endElement we try to unmarshall whole data using

```
   Events dom = (Events) um.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlChunk.toString()));
```

as you know by this time data would be converted into entities by sax parser so effectively we are numarshalling data which is shown in numbers as above.

I am able to process same file with no changes in jdk or code on win7 box. and it internally convert it to different character entities..
The same code when processed on win7 working fine !!! and character entities internally it is changing is -

```
converted internally to &#190;&#203;&#176;&#218;&#190;&#238;&#191;&#176; &#190;&#243;&#184;&#182;&#179;&#170; &#176;&#197;&#184;&#177;&#176;&#205;&#176;&#176;&#190;&#198;&#191;&#176; &#179;&#202; &#193;&#246;&#177;&#221; &#199;&#207;&#176;&#237; &#192;&#214;&#180;&#194;&#176;&#197;? by parser while parsing
```

. Now i am at loss here it does not make sense ...

Comment: you have most likely hosed your xml document.  probably converted it to a different character set at some point in its lifetime.  hard to tell, of course, without any code.

Comment: In fact when we look at the title of the question (not the content), it looks like xml entities were used. Is that so ?

Comment: flow is like this sax parser will parse the big file which have simple data <ev><data>ÀßµÅ°¡³ª¿°?</data></ev> once i get event ev from the sax i try to unmarshal this whole ev using  

Unmarshaller um = new Unmarshaller(com.xml.Events.class); 
Events dom = (Events) um.unmarshal(new StringReader(data as got above );

Comment: dear dystroy the data is processed two pahse as discussed above. So pahse one convert spacial characters into entities that's why i am getting this error.

Comment: how are you converting the xml chunks _back_ into a String for unmarshalling?  i would bet that is where you are breaking things.

Comment: 1) start tag start collecting data 2) end tag stop collecting and unmarshall - to specific using startElement and endElement sax events

Comment: are the contents of the elements themselves encoded xml fragments?  also, are you parsing the original file as an InputStream, and does it have the correct encoding in the xml header?

Comment: The same code when processed on win7 working fine !!! and character entities internally it is changing is - &#190;&#203;&#176;&#218;&#190;&#238;&#191;&#176; &#190;&#243;&#184;&#182;&#179;&#170; &#176;&#197;&#184;&#177;&#176;&#205;&#176;&#176;&#190;&#198;&#191;&#176; &#179;&#202; &#193;&#246;&#177;&#221; &#199;&#207;&#176;&#237; &#192;&#214;&#180;&#194;&#176;&#197;? . Now i am at loss here it does not make sense ...

Answer (score 4):

The supposed entity `&#56227;` is DBA3 which is in the Unicode surrogate character range.  This means either that your input is either UCS-16 / UTF-16, or it is garbled.  And if this is UCS-16, then the character entity representation is invalid XML.  The XML spec says:

> Char ::=  #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]

and

> Characters referred to using character references MUST match the production for Char.

---

Changing the platform of the XML parser is unlikely to fix this.

I'd look to the mechanisms that you used to process the input text (to make sure that you aren't getting the character encodings wrong) and to generate character references.  When creating the latter you need to test for surrogate pair "code units", and combine them into code points and then generate the character references from the code points.

---

The other thing to not is that if you are trying to use character references of CDATA to embed binary data in an XML document .... DON'T!  It won't work.  You have to convert  the binary data to Hex or Base64 or something like that, and embed *that* in the document.

Comment: agree with most of this.  however, if standard java xml tools are being used (correctly), the OP should not have to worry about anything like code points, surrogate pairs, or character references.

Comment: @jtahlborn - that is true, but clearly he isn't if he's got **malformed** character references

Comment: that's why i said "correctly".  my point is that he doesn't need to worry about surrogate pairs, he needs to figure out how to use the xml tools correctly.

Comment: Thank you everyone. But the given the process as listed above in my post. How do we solve this?

Comment: @RajenderSaini - Actually, the process is NOT described in your question.  Specifically, you don't say how the ASCII character sequence `"&#56227;"` is getting into the XML.  Are you putting it there?  If not, you know what is putting it there?  Because whatever is putting it there is the real cause of the problem ... and what you've got to fix.

Comment: Hi Stephen C - I am Sorry for not being clear. Here i am putting it again. 1) TO start with there is big xml file with <event> ....</event> tags. These event are not very big section. These are parsed using sax parser. Now when i get startElement for event, i start collecting all the data inside event tag and on endElement i stop collecting data. Next step i try to unmarshall this data using the code snip as shown above in post. This is where i get the error. As you know original data have been modified into character entities by the sax parser that's why it is showing this error.here.

Comment: Let me know if this clear the process or i will make some doc and post

Comment: So somehow there should be a mechanism to stop sax parser to convert data into character entities. That's why I thought of putting data into the CDATA section. But that did not help :(

Comment: It sounds like the SAX parser is >>describing<< the problem in terms of character references.  It certainly won't be >>inserting<< them.  So that means that you've either got bad (non-character) data in your input XML or you have made a mistake in the way you've told the infrastructure to decode it.

Comment: @StephenC thanks a lot for spending time for this problem and giving me insight how to go about this problem. I will post final solution once i am done with it.